# How to use pytessseract on remote server?

Tags: discord, discord.py, python-tesseract

**Problem**-

I am using a simple pytesseract + opencv implementation in my discord bot but tesseract is only working when i host it locally. On hosting the file on a remote server (In my case contabo). It shows the following error.

**Error**-

```
Extension 'cogs.Wlping' raised an error: ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'pytesseract'
```

**Code**-

```
async def on_message(msg):
    img = cv.imread("test.png")
    result = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng', config='--psm 11')
    await msg.channel.send(result)
```

I even added tesseract and pytesseract in the requirements.txt file on server. If there is anything else I should do please guide me through.

Comment: You have to make sure `pytesseract` is getting installed properly or not. Have you checked if your `pip install` is finishing without errors?

Comment: I did try that and it gave me an error. It said Image module not found (the import was in pytesseract init.py file)